# How to Use Inspect Element to Freeze in Google Survey Table

Tags: html, css

Thank you for visiting my question,

I am wondering if there is a way to freeze a row as in Excel Freeze in Google Survey Form.

For example (see the attached image):
[Example Table](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZsGR2.png)

I have a 90x100 table.
There is a constant scrolling back and forth to see if I have matched the answer correctly. Is there a way that I could freeze the top row while scrolling down the columns?

The table is in a Div class.

Thank you for your help

Comment: Please add your code for a better help.

Answer (score 0):

please provide some code snippet so that we can help you in better ways . you should look into CSS property called sticky if u want the top columns to stick on top.

```
position: sticky;
```

here is a [link to understand sticky property better](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_sticky_element.asp)